# MS Access 2000: Is it possible to open a connection to query Lotus Notes?

Tags: ms-access, connection, lotus-notes

Can I create either an ODBC connection or a connection string in VBA to get into a lotus notes database to pull data out of it?

Comment: Wow such great help on this site, I would prefer a connection string to keep from linking tables but the fact that this can be done saves me rediculous headaches.  Great help guys thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an ODBC connector for Lotus Notes called NotesSQL.  I used it years ago and you can find it on-line http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You need to install the "NotesSQL" ODBC driver for Notes (and you will need the Notes client on the machine running your VB code).

You can download the driver [here](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?cat=&q0=&pf=&k=ALL&pn=&pid=&rs=&S_TACT=104CBW71&status=Active&S_CMP=&b=&sr=1&q=notes+sql&ibm-search=Search).

And there is some more info [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a need to work with Lotus Notes in a while, but [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/lotus-notes) usually is a good resource for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Access, but I used to connect to Notes in a DTS package.  We had a special ODBC Notes driver that worked fairly well.

I think if you have the ODBC driver you can probably do it.

A word of warning, unless things have changed, Notes will throw you some curves.  The form value data types can change from one release to another and this can really confuse the  driver so that it returns nulls when there is actually data.

Good luck :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks!  The data I an pulling it nowhere near me so I would think I am in the dark confirming the data on that case... the option to do this in ODBC is being debated currently but we may wind up just doing a manual export through a query...  work in progress

Comment: It's been 9 years since I've mucked around with Notes.  As I recall, the problem we were having was that a field in the document held a date that was originally saved as a string.  Then, at some later point, they stopped saving it as a string and made it an actual date.  So... all the values that were stored as strings came through as NULLs.  There were other issues like that but my brain seems to have developed a leak.